# Using setState() with react-navigation gives me "can only update mounted component" issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As it stands, my app consists of three screens in a `StackNavigation` setup; first screen leads to the second leads to the third. Only the third screen makes use of `setState`.

Although the app works impeccably during the first run, issues start to arise as I close the third screen and reopen it another time. I start getting the warning where `setState` can only update a mounted or mounting component. There are no instances of `setState` in the mounting functions. Looking this issue up online yields me with surprisingly few results, none of which appear to be helpful for me in this case.

Since I am only using state in a single screen, I couldn't imagine this would be such an issue.

Comment: Include your code for your third screen and how you are navigating to/from it. Your description is too vague to give you anything but general advice/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined
>   component.

This means you can only perform set state on a mounted component.

The way to solve this is by setting a ref to the component and then checking if the ref exists before setting the state.

for example:

```
fetchUser(){
  if (this.refs.divRef) 
   this.setState({fetchedUser: true});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref="divRef">
      {this.state.fetchedUser}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why using ref??? declare `this.mounted=true` in `componentDidMount` and change it to `this.mounted=false` in `componentWillUnmount` and whereever you need check `this.mounted`